# Problem of refraction through curved surfaces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometric-optics

A point object is placed at the centre of a glass sphere of radius 6 cm and refractive index 1.5. Find the distance of virtual image from surface.

I applied the formula 
$$ \frac{\mu_2}{v}-\frac{\mu_1}{u} = \frac{\mu_2-\mu_1}{R}$$
$\mu_2$ is air so it is 1, $\mu_1$ is glass so it is 1.5, and
$u$ is negative because it is in opposite direction of ray from centre.

Which gives
$$ \frac{1}{v}-\frac{1.5}{-6} = \frac{-0.5}{6}$$
Solving this gives $v=-3$
But the object is at the centre of the sphere so the rays originating from there must meet at the centre as they will be perpendicular to the surface.

What is wrong with my application of the formula?

Comment: It is not clear which sign convention you are using.